# Angular - Creating an HTML link for an element without XSS removing it

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table that is being generated from an object in my application. This table loops over the data and outputs it into the html.

I am trying to pass an HTML link over to the table to be clicked on but it is getting stripped out by angular?

```
 output[i] = {
   'Rule Number': rn,
   'Outcome': this.parentRuleData[i].Value,
   'Impacted Users': '<a style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="viewImpactedUsers('+this.parentRuleData[i].RuleParentID+')">'+Number(iu)+'</a>'
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of gridView | filter: filterStringGrid">
   <td *ngFor="let key of item | keys" [innerHTML]="item[key]"></td>
</tr>
```

Error: WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

How else can I generate this link with event since its not really a router link that would go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Angular that your HTML is safe. In your case, I'd suggest creating a pipe that returns a `SafeHtml` object. To do that, in the pipe, inject `DomSanitizer` an then call `bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html)`:

```
return domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
```

With such a pipe, you could do, assuming you named it `SafePipe`:

```
[innerHTML]="item[key]|safe"
```

Of course, you could also add a method in your component that does the same, but it is less reusable:

```
public sanitize(html: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

And then,

```
[innerHTML]="santize(item[key])"
```

Of course, do this only if you're absolutely sure your HTML IS safe.

Comment: I will have to play around this this. I took the second approach just to make sure everything would play nice. While the XSS message is no longer showing and the HTML in the DOM shows the link correctly, nothing happens onClick. I assume the binding and everything would be the same but it doesn't appear to be triggering the method.

Comment: Aah, I hadn't looked at what the HTML looked like. Sorry, but you can't add angular template HTML with this method to a page. Angular templates must be compiled by the Angular compiler, and this HTML hasn't been.